# Why doesn't 802.11 based technologies LTE need time sync?

Tags: wireless

I have been reading on 802.11p vs C-V2x, the two technologies for vehicular communications. One disadvantage for C-V2x that is frequently mentioned is that C-V2x needs all the UEs to be time-synced which may not be possible in out-of-coverage areas.

My question is why doesn't 802.11 based technologies need the same time sync ? C-V2x is based on LTE and time-sync is needed for resource scheduling.

Comment: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/white-paper/CITSCOMPWP.pdf

Comment: https://news.transportation.org/Documents/spectrum%20letter.pdf

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 the second link is very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

802.11 is generally a collision detection/avoidance system with uncoordinated stations.

It simply sacrifices rate by depending on "silent stretches" to coordinate medium access, and by requiring a significant amount of synchronization data to be inserted in the frame.

Comment: so in LTE, is it correct to say that there is no concept of collisions as everything is scheduled ?